# Could not connect to SVN Repository. Could not resolve hostname

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, connect

I try connect to SVN Repository and get `SvnRepositoryIOException`: Could not resolve hostname: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
The same error when I try commit or update project or using TortoiseSVN.
We use kerio, but I think it's something else, because another computer with similar settings can connect successful. I tried everything. I am thinking reset my operating system already. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If an answer helped you, do please mark with the green tick so others can see which answer was the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**
It was DNS problem. My computer couldn't find DNS of repository server. I add another DNS in LAN connection settings and it works! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If both SVN clients give the same result then it suggests the problem is somewhere else.

Some things to try:

- Can you ping the host? If so, what happens if you connect with a Web browser - can you browse any HTTP version of the Subversion repository that might be available?
- If you can't resolve the host, does the other host have a VPN, or some fancy settings in the `hosts` file to tell the PC about the repository?
- Are your authentication settings correct?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you are operating from behind a proxy. If you are you can set these details in the Tortoise settings panel.

Have you tried connecting to another SVN server to test your tortoise?

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with this if IPv6 is enabled and used over a wireless router that does not support the IPv6 protocol well. Try disabling in your network properties temporarily to see if that fixes it.