# SVN not commiting, no errors shown

Tags: tortoisesvn, commit, ankhsvn

Recently I've been having problems with AnkhSVN. When I want to commit, the window "Committing..." comes up and normally it then asks to authenticate, but it doesn't do that anymore, it doesn't do anything anymore. I've waited for an hour but still nothing happens and I receive no error, it just doesn't do anything.

I've found no solutions online, so I hope anyone of you has encountered the same problem and can help me out. I don't know how to check which version I'm using and how to update it. I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Any help would be appreciated.

I already tried the following and it didn't help:
- restart Visual Studio
- restart pc
- clear authentication cache

**Update:** problem is not only AnkhSVN, the same problem occurs with TortoiseSVN...

Comment: It's kinda strange that you don't get any prompts at all and nothing happens. Did you try a command-line client? What's the behavior there? 
E.g. try the command-line "svn commit" against the working copy.
What about a checkout or other operations, do they work?

Comment: Against which identity repository is your SVN server authenticating users? LDAP? Is it available?

Comment: I think I might be having the same problem as described here, DNS:  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500218/could-not-connect-to-svn-repository-could-not-resolve-hostname-solved[link] with the difference that I don't know how to fix it :s Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem with the help of a colleague. I wish I could give a clear explanation but unfortunately the problem remains strange to me. We had to create a new network adapter and pass that to the Virtual Machine to fix it. I assume a corrupt network adapter :s